# Cmake 3.1 + "Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS" importing another .proto error

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm still fairly new to CMAKE, but I'm using `find_package(Protobuf Requried)` to compile my .proto files as part of the build, and I'm having trouble getting imports to work, and I'm well and truly stumped.

I have 2 .proto files in the same direcotry, "protobuf" named "A.proto" and "B.proto"

Without an import, they compile fine.

If I change A.proto to have an import to B:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "B.proto";


message MyMessage
{}
```

With a CMakeLists.txt file that sets the `Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS` variable correctly (I think):

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
set(Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS ${Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf) 

...

protobuf_generate(TARGET ${MY_PROJECT_NAME})
```

I get this on build:

```
  Running cpp protocol buffer compiler on protobuf/A.proto
  B.proto: File not found.
  protobuf/A.proto:3:1: Import "B.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I feel like i'm taking crazy pills! :)

Answer (score 5):

So i found the answer, although it took some hacking. Bascially I just read all the CMAKE files associated with Protobuf until I figured it out. There's probably better docs out there but I couldn't find.

Short Story:

if you call `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP`, it respects setting a `Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS` variable.

However if you directly call the `protobuf_generate` for a target as I do, the variable is ignored.

The answer is to call `protobuf_generate` with an argument of IMPORT_DIRS, such as:

`protobuf_generate(TARGET ${MY_PROJECT_NAME} IMPORT_DIRS protobuf)`

IMPORT_DIRS is a multi argument, you can supply several.

Here's the relevant code:

```
function(protobuf_generate)
  include(CMakeParseArguments)

  set(_options APPEND_PATH)
  set(_singleargs LANGUAGE OUT_VAR EXPORT_MACRO PROTOC_OUT_DIR PLUGIN)
  if(COMMAND target_sources)
    list(APPEND _singleargs TARGET)
  endif()
  set(_multiargs PROTOS IMPORT_DIRS GENERATE_EXTENSIONS)

  cmake_parse_arguments(protobuf_generate "${_options}" "${_singleargs}" "${_multiargs}" "${ARGN}")
```

I hope this will save someone headache in the future!

Comment: the "relevant code" is confusing. a link to the [docs](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/cmake_protobuf_generate.md) would be enough